# Get main domain url without hardcoding

Tags: python, django

In Django, I have many sub domains and these have a theme installed to it. The problem is now I need to implement a function that redirects to the main domain of my project. For example when pressing a link ("Go to main domain") in the sub domain theme it will take them to the main domain.

I can hard code this, but it's not really nice. So I'm looking for other solutions to this.

This is a hardcoded way in `views.py`:

```
def network_url(request):
    return redirect('https://domain.com/')
```

So how do I create a function that do not require to hardcode the main domain?

Comment: You can get it from request object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store your links in `settings.py`.

```
MAIN_DOMAIN_LINK = 'https://domain.com/'
```

Then, you can simply access them by importing `django.conf.settings` in your views:

```
from django.conf import settings

def network_url(request):
    return redirect(settings.MAIN_DOMAIN_LINK)
```

Hope this helps. Docs [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def network_url(request):
    return redirect(request.META.get("HTTP_HOST"))
```